# Get arrayList populated on event values from backing bean

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, primefaces

i populate my arrayList on onDrop event, now when I try to retrieve it via javascript, it does not have any value

backing bean:

```
List<String> arr..
 public void onDrop(DragDropEvent event) {
    arr.add(event.getDragId());
}
```

jsf code:

```
<h:inputHidden id="hidden" value=#{bean.arr}/>
```

javascript function:

```
function get(){
 var a = document.getElementById("hidden");
 alert(a.value);
}
```

alert returns `[]` but I have now a populated arrayList after onDrop is fired several times but it seems that it does not get the values. how can i retrieve those values in the arrayList?

EDIT:

here's the one using the onDrop event

```
<p:outputPanel id="op" ... > 
<p:droppable ... >
<p:ajax ... listener="#{bean.onDrop}"/>
```

Comment: where did you attach the onDrop event in your jsf code?

Comment: when is the javascript get() method being called ?

Comment: it's called by `<p:commandButton>`

Answer (score 0):

try declaring its Getters and Setters, sometimes value is not reached because of that even if variable, string or array does exist

```
//Getter
//public List<String> getArr...
//   return arr...

//Setter
//public void setArr...
//   this.arr =...
```

If you're using NetBeans just use Refactor...